# How to draw arrow head with D3 (Responsive)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to draw thermometer kind of bar by using D3.js version 3. I have done drawing basic responsive rectangle with two filled colors. However i have problem figuring out arrow heads. I have added the screenshot and code the below. Thanks for your kind help guys!!

[image]

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>
    #temp_pue_wrapper {
        position: relative;
        height: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        /* padding-bottom will be overwritten by JavaScript later */
        padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
    #temp_pue_wrapper > svg {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <div id="temp_pue_wrapper"></div>
    
    <script>
    var width = 500,
        height = 30,
        tmp_wrapper = d3.select("#temp_pue_wrapper")
            .attr(
                "style",
                "padding-bottom: " + Math.ceil(height * 85 / width) + "%"
            )
            .append("svg")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);
      
    var gradient = tmp_wrapper.append("defs")
       .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient")
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "0%")
      .attr("x2", "100%")
      .attr("y2", "0%")
      .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");
    
    gradient.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "0%")
        .attr("stop-color", "#228582")
        .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
    
    gradient.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "50%")
        .attr("stop-color", "#228582")
        .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
     
    gradient.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "50%")
        .attr("stop-color", "#C23439")
        .attr("stop-opacity", 1); 
    
    gradient.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "100%")
        .attr("stop-color", "#C23439")
        .attr("stop-opacity", 1); 
     
    tmp_wrapper.append('rect')
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .attr("fill", "url(#gradient)");
      
    </script>
```

Comment: It's as simple as looking at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_arrows.asp). Now, for this you'll probably need to add more boldness, but you get the basic idea.

Comment: so far it's not what i want. Thanks for your reply, anyway, i did it by using line graph and triangle shape. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out by using triangle shape and line graph.

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>
    #temp_pue_wrapper {
        position: relative;
        height: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        /* padding-bottom will be overwritten by JavaScript later */
        padding-bottom: 100%;
  
    }
    #temp_pue_wrapper > svg {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
 
  

 path {
  fill: none;

 } 
    </style>
    <div id="temp_pue_wrapper"></div>
 

    <script>
    var width = 500,
        height = 30,
        tmp_wrapper = d3.select("#temp_pue_wrapper")
            .attr(
                "style",
                "padding-bottom: " + Math.ceil(height * 80 / width) + "%"
            )
            .append("svg")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);
    
      
    var gradient = tmp_wrapper.append("defs")
       .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient")
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "0%")
      .attr("x2", "100%")
      .attr("y2", "0%")
      .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");
    
    gradient.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "0%")
        .attr("stop-color", "#228582")
        .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
    
    gradient.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "50%")
        .attr("stop-color", "#228582")
        .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
     
    gradient.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "50%")
        .attr("stop-color", "#C23439")
        .attr("stop-opacity", 1); 
    
    gradient.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "100%")
        .attr("stop-color", "#C23439")
        .attr("stop-opacity", 1); 

 tmp_wrapper.append('rect')
      .attr("width", "88.8%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .attr("x", "29px")
      .attr("y", "0px")   
      .attr("fill", "url(#gradient)")
   .attr("class","foo");
   
 tmp_wrapper.append("svg:path")  // Fixed.
   .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up").size(400))
   .style("fill", "#228582")
   .attr ("transform", "translate(17,15) rotate (-90)");
    
 tmp_wrapper.append("svg:path")  // Fixed.
   .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up").size(400))
   .style("fill", "#C23439")
   .attr ("transform", "translate(485,15) rotate (90)"); 

   

  //This is the accessor function we talked about above
 var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
   .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
   .interpolate('linear');

 //The data for our line
 var lineData = [ 
   { "x": -5,   "y": 0},  
   { "x": 20,  "y": 0},
   { "x": -5,  "y": 15}, 
   { "x": 20,  "y": 30},
   { "x": -5,  "y": 30},  
   { "x": -30, "y": 15},
   { "x": -5, "y": 0}

 ];
   
 //The line SVG Path we draw
 var lineGraph = tmp_wrapper.append("path")
   .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
   .style("fill", "#228582"); 

  var lineGraph1 = tmp_wrapper.append("path")
   .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
   .style("fill", "#C23439")
   .attr ("transform", "translate(502,30) rotate(180)"); 
     
    </script>
```